# I can't run a function from the servise layer in Django

Tags: python, django, function

I am a novice programmer. I'm trying to integrate PayPal IPN into my project, implement recurring subscription payments.

I wrote a function that works fine in the console, BUT I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO RUN THIS FUNCTION SO THAT IT WOULD WORK AUTOMATICALLY. The ideal option for me would be if, when the data I need appears in the PayPal table, the IPN function would automatically start and perform the actions I need.

For example, when these conditions appear in the table:

```
ipn = PayPalIPN.objects.filter(payment_status='Completed').order_by("-pk")[:20]
```

my function would start, bypass the data in the table and perform the actions that I needed.

I have tried such methods:

```
def Check_1():
if ipn.exists():
    return Subscription()

def Check_2():
if ipn.count() > 0:
    return Subscription()

def Check_3():
if len(ipn) > 0:
    return Subscription()
```

From the console, the Subscription() function is started, and works well. But when I write this in a Python document (in the service layer), nothing works. I do not know how to run it all.

I don't even know how to run this function from a class on a sheet views.py

That's how I tried to run the Subscription() function from a sheet views.py :

```
    class Successful_payment(ListView):
        model = Odin
        template_name = "successful_payment.html"
        context_object_name = 'successful_payment'

       ipn = PayPalIPN.objects.filter(payment_status='Completed').order_by("-pk")[:20]

        if len(ipn) > 0:
            Subscription()
```

As a result, the function only works when the server is restarted. When calling the same page "successful_payment.html " the function is not called and is not executed.

Here is the function itself:

```
def Subscription():
for z in ipn:
    user_z = User.objects.get(id=(int(z.custom)))
        if z.payment_gross == 25:
            user_z.paid_until = plus_days(count='monthly')
            user_z.save()
        z.save()
```

I found a solution to the problem. solved the issue using the get_context_data function:

```
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    ipn = PayPalIPN.objects.filter(payment_status='Completed').order_by(
    "-pk")[:20]
    Podpiska(ipn)
    return context
```

Comment: Read the docs: [docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) 